# passing docker environment variables to .net core

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I've followed this [article](https://cmelendeztech.com/posts/2017/02/using-docker-env-vars-in-dotnet-core.html) and the code on the [github](https://github.com/christianhxc/hellodocker/blob/master/HelloDocker/Startup.cs) doesn't compile, tutorial is outdated I think. (`Configuration = builder.Build();`) throws error. So how can I access env passed from docker?

---

**docker-compose**

```
  myproj:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
    restart: on-failure
    working_dir: /MyProj
    command: bash -c "dotnet build MyProj.csproj && dotnet bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/MyProj.dll"
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - "./MyProj:/MyProj"
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: database
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: Password
```

---

**Startup.cs**

```
public Service()
{
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DATABASE_PASSWORD"); // null
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
// For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass env variable in build argument.
E.g.

```
--build-arg ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

Use below variable to set value:

`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`

Code:

```
var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
```

You can use above variable in your code for environment name .

Answer (score 30):

The standard approach to access environment variables in a .NET Core application is to use the static method

```
public static string GetEnvironmentVariable (string variable);
```

So in your case irrespective of what you pass either in the docker run command or through the launch settings file just use this method . As an example for getting the Database password use this

```
string dbPassword = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DATABASE_PASSWORD");
```

Additionally be sure to define the environment variables part of the dockerfile by adding the line

```
ENV DATABASE_PASSWORD some_default_value_or_can_be_empty
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is also worth nothing that you can inject environment variables in to `IConfiguration` using the `EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider` from .NET Core 2.1, and above. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#environment-variables-configuration-provider

Comment: What would be the most likely reason that this doesn't work? When getting the environment variable it is empty.

Comment: Is it defined in the dockerfile...?

Comment: same for me, I've tried to pass environment variables using 'docker run -e' and 'docker run --env-file' and get null in my code. I've tried to print all environment variables my .net core 3.1 app has access to in container and I can only see 'ASPNETCORE_URLS, DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER, PATH, HOSTNAME, HOME and PATH' but not my custom env variables...

Comment: If you want to pass environment variable using -e you need to use that syntax: `docker run -ti -e "RemoteIp=1.23.4.56" myImageTag`

Comment: And order or arguments matters. So if you're using commandline arguments, try moving it to the end, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 15):

You could read the values with `IConfiguration` which all done for you by default. If you have configured your host with defaults in `Program.cs`, then it will load the configuration in the following order

1. appsetting.json
2. appsettings..json
3. secret.json
4. environment variables
5. cli args

For example, you could have a class

```
    public class DatabaseSettings
    {
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

then in your `Startup.cs` you can read the values and bind them to a `DatabaseSettings` object.

`var credentials = Configuration.GetSection("Database").Get<DatabaseSettings>();`

Note: Your environment variables must have double underscores to separate between the key and the value section.

For example, if you were to pass this from `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.Development.json` file, this hierarchical `JSON` object

```
  "Database": {
    "Host": "address",
    "Password": "password" 
  }
```

Can be also represented when flattened like this

```
"Database:Host":"address",
"Database:Password":"Password"
```

Or when passed as environment variable can be done as

```
Database__Host=address
Database__Password=password
```

Remember, you need double underscore.

Comment: Can we define this variable in docker file and use in appsetting.json

Comment: How to use this in dockercompose file?

Comment: @Arti have not done this with docker compose, but a quick search points to this documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/ Is this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone uses Docker-compose.yml environment variables instead of appsettings.json add the following code to IHostBuilder

string someVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment Variable Name");

Comment: Insn't this already suggested in the accepted answerr? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58319079/1574221)