# .Net App in Docker - Startup Can't Find Azure App Configuration

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-configuration

I'm working to move my app from an app service into a docker container.
I've added a dockerfile and other standard docker requirements.

My app previously had been using Azure App Configuration to provide a good portion of the configuration settings during startup.

Here's the key part of my Startup.CS

[image: configBuilder]

When I run this typically, it gets the connection string from the Environment settings, and calls out to the service and retrieves the configuration.

The environment settings are being found in the Docker startup.
However, the service call part isn't working and none of those settings are being made available.

How can I enable this?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to read the **Environment variables** and **Connection Strings** is below:

```cs
 var Appconfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
        //Reading config values from local.settings.json
        var appSetValue = Appconfig["MyCustomSetting"];
        //Reading Application Settings 
        var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyCustomSetting");
        //Reading Connection Strings 
        var mycusString = Appconfig.GetConnectionString("MyCustomSetting");
```

> **FunctionAppDirectory** sets the directory to find your `local.settings.json` file. Set `optional` to true because we won’t have the file when we deploy. **AddEnvironmentVariables** will pick up both App Settings and Connection Strings from Azure settings. Refer [here](https://medium.com/awesome-azure/azure-reading-application-settings-in-azure-functions-asp-net-core-1dea56cf67cf)

Refer [Azure Function Configuration and Secrets Management on Startup.cs](https://damienbod.com/2020/07/12/azure-functions-configuration-and-secrets-management/)

Comment: This is true, but this is not using Azure App Configuration service.

Comment: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable() & Appconfig.GetConnectionString() can get the Azure App Configuration values

Comment: In Azure Function we can get all Application Configurations (`App Settings` & `Connection String`) settings using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()`

Comment: Ahh ok, so the issue is it works great in an app service, but when I move it into a docker container those settings never show up.

Comment: Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58319079/15997690)